# instead of catching Java MalformedURLException, build failing

Tags: java, exception, build, try-catch, jsoup

New to Java, so please bear with me:
(and please note that this qestion is about Java Exceptions, not Jsoup)

when using Jsoup in order to get Html page: (Jsoup.connect(current_url._name).get();) , I tried to catch all possible 5 exceptions according to the Jsoup documentation: [here](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/)

the program works fine with good URLs, but when I intentionally misspelled 1 URL to check what happens, I was surprised to see that the exception wasn't catch, instead the program start running, then the "Build failed"? 
when only building the program there is no failure, so I think it isn't really
build issue.

here is the code:

```
// load html and check them:
    for(URL current_url : URLs)
    {
        // no keyword - all getting 'yes'
        if(keywords.isEmpty())
        {
            current_url._stat = URL_stat.YES;
        }
        // there are keywords - get pages and check them
        else
        {
            Document html_doc;
            // try to get document and catch all errors
            try
            {
                html_doc = Jsoup.connect(current_url._name).get();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("the request " + current_url._name +
                                   " URL is malformed");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                current_url._stat = URL_stat.ERROR;
            }
            catch(HttpStatusException e)
            {
                System.out.println("page " + current_url._name + " response"
                                   + " is not ok");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                current_url._stat = URL_stat.ERROR;
            }
            catch(UnsupportedMimeTypeException e)
            {
                System.out.println("page " + current_url._name+ " mime type"
                                   + " is not supported");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                current_url._stat = URL_stat.ERROR;
            }
            catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
            {
                System.out.println("connection to " + current_url._name + 
                                   " times out");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                current_url._stat = URL_stat.ERROR;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("an error occurred while getting page " 
                                   + current_url._name);
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                current_url._stat = URL_stat.ERROR;
            }
            // check if document has paragraphs, if not mark - no

        }
    }
```

and the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: ttp://cooking.nytimes.com/topics/what-to-cook-this-week
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:76)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:36)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
at ex2.Ex2.main(Ex2.java:123)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ttp
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:74)
... 3 more
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-     snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the first exception being thrown is an IllegalArgumentException, which you have not defined in any of your catch clauses, thus preventing you from getting your custom error messages in any other catch blocks.